# Keeping client socket open after connection until it's needed

Tags: c++, sockets, client-server, asio

i am trying to build a server-client architecture in c++ using asio and i'm encountering a problem. My client socket sends only one thing to the server then it closes the connection as far as i can tell. How should i approach the situation so that i can make the client connect to the server, then send requests to the user whenever it is needed.

Example: I have an interface made in console in which the user needs to login. Once the user inputs the strings needed to login, the client sends a request to the server to check if it's ok, if so, it returns an OK message, and proceeds to let the user do a number of things: write a post, check his profile, etc. and whenever he does something, a request for data needs to be sent to the server

For now i only send the login request, server says it's ok then the connection ends

Here is the code for the client socket:

```
if (argc != 2)
        {
            std::cerr << "Usage: client <host>" << std::endl;
            return 1;
        }

        // Socket Parameters
        const unsigned port = 27015;
        auto ip_address = asio::ip::make_address_v4(argv[1]);
        auto endpoint = tcp::endpoint{ ip_address, port };

        // Creating and Connecting the Socket
        asio::io_context io_context;
        auto resolver = tcp::resolver{ io_context };
        auto endpoints = resolver.resolve(endpoint);

        auto socket = tcp::socket{ io_context };
        asio::socket_base::keep_alive option(true);
        socket.set_option(option);
        asio::connect(socket, endpoints);

        std::array<char, 5000> buf;

        asio::error_code ignored_error;
        std::string username="admin",password="adminpass";
        std::stringstream is(buf.data());
        {
            cereal::JSONInputArchive archive_in(is);
            archive_in(username,password);
        }

        asio::write(socket, asio::buffer(buf), ignored_error);
```

I dont know if i should put the socket write in a for, but since i want to read and send diferent types of data each time i don't think that helps me.

Other code needed:
Server Socket:
.cpp

```
#include "ServerSocket.h"
#include <optional>

tcp::acceptor*
ServerSocket::InitAcceptor()
{
    try
    {
        return new tcp::acceptor(io_context, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), 27015));
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
    return nullptr;
}

tcp::socket*
ServerSocket::InitSocket()
{
    try
    {
        return new tcp::socket(io_context);
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
    return nullptr;
}

void
ServerSocket::StartServerSocket()
{
    try
    {
        std::cout << "Server started";
        acceptor->accept(*socket);
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}

std::optional<std::string>
ServerSocket::RecieveData()
{
    try
    {
        char data[5000];
        for (;;)
        {
            asio::error_code error;
            size_t length = socket->read_some(asio::buffer(data), error);
            if (error == asio::error::eof) return std::nullopt; // Connection closed cleanly by peer.
            else if (error)
                throw asio::system_error(error); // Some other error.
            return std::string{ data, length };
        }
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
    return {};
}

ServerSocket* ServerSocket::instance(nullptr);

ServerSocket* ServerSocket::GetInstance()
{
    if (instance == nullptr)
    {
        instance = new ServerSocket();
    }
    return instance;
}
```

.h

```
#pragma once
#include <asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <optional>

using asio::ip::tcp;

class ServerSocket
{
public:
    ServerSocket(ServerSocket& otherSingleton) = delete;
    void operator= (const ServerSocket& copySingleton) = delete;

    tcp::acceptor* InitAcceptor();
    tcp::socket* InitSocket();
    void StartServerSocket();
    void SendData(std::string);
    std::optional<std::string> RecieveData();

    static ServerSocket* GetInstance();

private:
    static ServerSocket* instance;

    tcp::acceptor* acceptor;
    tcp::socket* socket;
    asio::io_context io_context;

    ServerSocket()
    {
        acceptor = InitAcceptor();
        socket = InitSocket();
    }

    ~ServerSocket() {
        delete socket;
        delete acceptor;
        std::cout << "Server closed";
    }
};
```

And the connection which links the messages sent to the server from the client with the database
.h

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include "DBUser.h"
#include "DBPost.h"

class Communication
{
public:
    enum class Operations {
        eLogin,
        eRegister,
        eReadUser,
        eCreatePost,
        eReadPost,
        eUpdatePost,
        eDeletePost
    };
    void ExecuteOperation(Operations operation,const std::array<char, 5000>& buffer);
};
```

.cpp

```
#include "Communication.h"

void Communication::ExecuteOperation(Operations operation,const std::array<char, 5000>& buffer)
{
    switch (operation)
    {
    case Communication::Operations::eLogin:
    {
        DBUser* user = DBUser::getInstance();
        std::string username, password;
        std::stringstream is(buffer.data());
        {
            cereal::JSONInputArchive archive_in(is);
            archive_in(username, password);
        }
        try
        {
            user->LoginUser(username, password);
        }
        catch (const std::exception& e)
        {
            std::cout << e.what();
        }
        break;
    }
    case Communication::Operations::eRegister:
    {
        DBUser* user = DBUser::getInstance();
        std::string username, password;
        std::stringstream is(buffer.data());
        {
            cereal::JSONInputArchive archive_in(is);
            archive_in(username, password);
        }
        try
        {
            user->CreateUser(username, password);
        }
        catch (const std::exception& e)
        {
            std::cout << e.what();
        }
        break;
    }
    case Communication::Operations::eReadUser:
    {
        DBUser* user = DBUser::getInstance();
        user->ReadUser();
        break;
    }
    case Communication::Operations::eCreatePost:
    {
        DBPost post;
        std::string postBody, userID;
        std::stringstream is(buffer.data());
        {
            cereal::JSONInputArchive archive_in(is);
            archive_in(userID,postBody);
        }
        try
        {
            post.CreatePost(userID, postBody);
        }
        catch (const std::exception& e)
        {
            std::cout << e.what();
        }
        break;
    }
    case Communication::Operations::eReadPost:
    {
        DBPost post;
        std::string user;
        std::stringstream is(buffer.data());
        {
            cereal::JSONInputArchive archive_in(is);
            archive_in(user);
        }
        post.ReadPost(user);
        break;
    }
    case Communication::Operations::eUpdatePost:
    {
        break;
    }
    case Communication::Operations::eDeletePost:
    {
        break;
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like the **client code** is sending the login request, and then closing.  The *server* cannot deny the *client* from closing the socket.

Comment: Unrelated: in `ServerSocket::RecieveData`, there doesn't seem to be a point to the `for(;;;)`. Every path returns or throws.

Comment: @Eljay my problem is how to keep alive the socket even after it sends a request to the server

Comment: @user4581301 i thought doing that might help with my client not shutting down instantly

Comment: You have some functions involved in construction catching exceptions and then returning `nullptr`. This  is a bad idea because it allows an object that didn't successfully finish construction to exist and subsequently be used in an ill-configured state. Consider letting the exceptions propagate to the code that constructs the object and make it deal with not being able to get a valid object. This will also allows you to have automatic allocations and eliminate the need worry about destruction and maybe even that whole Rule of Three jazz.

Comment: Eljay's probably right, but there isn't enough client code to prove it or offer suggestions on how to fix it. You're making one of the classic programming mistakes: Adding code to fix a bug that you haven't isolated and understood. When you don't know what's causing the bug, **remove** code until you can see the problem through the noise. Adding code just adds more noise. And probably more bugs.